# How to save multiple checkbox values to local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, local-storage

I'm trying to save multiple check boxes in local storage, see the code below and you get the idea.

What I have tried so far:

```
$(function () {
var data = localStorage.getItem("favorite");

if (data !== null) {
    $("input[name='favorites']").attr("checked", "checked");
}
});
$("input[name='favorites']").click(function () {

if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    localStorage.setItem("favorite", $(this).val());
} else {
    localStorage.removeItem("favorite");
}
});
```

Html

```
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="favorite1" id="like">
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="favorite2" id="like1">
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="favorite3" id="like2">
```

Comment: those checkboxes all have the same name ....why? Also you are trying to set them all to same key in storage...need to use array to do that. Each will overwrite the last

Comment: Ok, well I wouldn't have asked the question if I knew how to do it, would I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply serialize them.

```
$('.faChkRnd').on('click', function() {
    var fav, favs = [];
    $('.faChkRnd').each(function() { // run through each of the checkboxes
        fav = {id: $(this).attr('id'), value: $(this).prop('checked')};
        favs.push(fav);
    }
    localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(favs));
});
```

They will be saved in a JSON like so:

```
"[{\"id\": \"like\", \"value\": true},{\"id\": \"like2\", \"value\": true},{\"id\": \"like3\", \"value\": true}]"
```

Which you can later load:

```
var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
```

And loop through to reassign:

```
for (var i=0; i<favorites.length; i++) {
    $('#' + favorites[i].id ).prop('checked', favorites[i].value);
}
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2m04prmz/2/). You can check a box, and refresh to see the values loaded.

Comment: Thanks so much! that works great. only problem now is that the checkbox onclick background colour change isn't saved. lol I incorrectly assumed that if the box was checked then it would save the colour, but it didn't. haha!

Comment: Well if you style it with CSS (`.faChkRnd:checked { /* ... style ... */ }`) it will [work properly](https://jsfiddle.net/2m04prmz/3/)!

Answer (score 2):

That would be less operations with arrays you can do without 'IF'.
With every click simply re-save all the selected checkboxes.

```
$("input[name='favorites']").click(function () {
   var c = [];
   $(this).is(":checked").each(function (i) {
       c.push( $(this).attr('id') );
       localStorage.setItem("favorite", JSON.stringify(c));
   });         
});
```

To get the value:

```
var fav = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favorite"));
```

Comment: Why did you nest the click events?

Comment: in localStorage will have a key "favorite" value of serialized to a string array "[ \"like\", \"like1\"]"

Answer (score 1):

We have two cases here

**Case 1 :**

Want to store checkbox values for elements with different names 
here is an example for this scenario :

```
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="favorite1" id="like" value="val1">
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="favorite2" id="like1" value="val2">
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="favorite3" id="like2" value="val3">
```

here all the checkboxs have a name that starts with `favorite`, so we can reference them using this information and then store each checkbox name with its appropriate value as a separate item in the `localStorage`
Here is the JS code:

```
$("input[name*='favorite']").change(function () {
    var name = $(this).attr('name'),
        value = $(this).val();

    localStorage.setItem(name,value);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem(name));        
});
```

**Case 2 :**

We want to reference multiple checkboxs with the **same name**.
First we change the value of the name attribute as it is shown in the following :

```
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="favorite" id="like" value="val1">
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="favorite" id="like1" value="val2">
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="favorite" id="like2" value="val3">
```

Second we get the data like we've done before but the special thing this time is that the `eventListener` is fired when each element with that name  change the checked property, so the value is generated again with the proper value and it is an **array** that is for sure because we have **multiple values**
Now the last trick is to convert that array of values into a string, using the awesomeness of the **JSON** object like this :

```
var valueStringified = JSON.stringify(value);
```

**OR** simple enough use your own delimiter to join the array values, for example :

```
var valueStringified  = value.join(',');
```

Now store it to your localStorage as **one string**

```
localStorage.setItem('favorite',valueStringified);
```

And when you want to retrieve the value of the element, it is very simple just get the item name `localStorage.getItem('favorite')` and then **split** it to get an array using the previous delimiter, something like that :

```
var values = localStorage.getItem('favorite').split(',');
```

**Finally that's it**

[Here is a jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/2pxrsoyc/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @hamism, But this doesn't work as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/sb8gmdvm/

Comment: As i can see in the console there is an error clamaing that jQuery is not there may be you forget to include it.