# checkbox value resets on page reload using local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I was working on a module which lets user compare different products,every time user select on a checkbox associated with it, its got appended to compare box,its url get updated for e.g.: `compare.php?id=23,43,23`,and on next page parse these id's to get the result corresponding to those id's, now I'm stuck on a problem when user navigate on multiple pages using pagination or uses Ajax filter to filter result, whole checkbox url get reset to earlier url i.e `compare.php`.
Now all I want is to hold the selected checkboxes value on page refresh, i know I can do it via

```
if(isset($_GET['category'])){
    if(in_array($category_row['course_category_name'],$_GET['category']))
        $category_check='checked="checked"';
    else
        $category_check="";
}
```

But I don't want to use this approach, problem with this approach is, i want to store those checkbox for longer time or for multiple browsing sessions.
After lots of googling I found out it can be achieved via browser's local storage.

So guys help me to keep checkbox value checked on page reload using local storage.

My code is : 
 HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin: 0px">
    <div class="checkbox-inline col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="compare-result" id="compare-<?php echo $course_id;?>" value="<?php echo $course_id;?>">Compare</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT :**

Before marking this as duplicate questions kindly read the full problem I know this is somehow related to other question but if go into detail of this problem, you will find it different,as I said on every checkbox selection my compare box which hold the selected checkbox id's and their count and its url get updated and on page reload it get reset to compare.php and count set to 0 ,so what would I like to do is to store the selected checkbox id's and compare's box url into the local storage

**EDIT--2**

I am able to retrieve previous selected items after page reload using local storage,in following fiddle you guys can clearly see how url is changing on selection of each items, now only problem is I also want to track the count of selected items and compare url throughout the whole time,Hope you will be able to understand problem with the fiddle here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/uqcovkfo/13/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save multiple checkbox values to local storage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831745/how-to-save-multiple-checkbox-values-to-local-storage)

Comment: store your course id in local storage and on page load you can check your checkbox by js.

Comment: @Schlaus I saw that link but this solves my problem partially, as I said on every checkbox selection my compare box which hold the selected checkbox id's and their count and its url get updated and on page reload it get reset to `compare.php` ,so what would I like to do is to store the selected checkbox id's and compare's box url into the local storage

Comment: @parvez Well, you know how to update the url, and that link tells you how to store & retrieve the checkboxes' values. Isn't that just about what you need? Just update the url when restoring the selections after page load.

Comment: @Schalus,see I created a js fiddle,what I want is after selecting checkbox items when user visit next time, he/she should find those selected items in compare basked, in fiddle you can clearly see how compare url is changing on each selection,i am able to retrieve the previous selected checkbox local storage ,now only problem is how can I keep the count of items and compare url before last reload.
I hope through this fiddle you will understand what I'm trying to say, here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/uqcovkfo/13/